# how to do build of the tags froms svn in jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, ant, build, tagging

I have been using subversion tagging plugin to do the tagging of the builds of the  jobs .
 I want to do the builds of these tags now. 
Is there some plugin to do the build of these tags from build history or some other way to do the same.

To obtain a build of the particular tag  i had to temporarily create a new job .. and gave the repository location of the tag to do the build.
But this is cumbersome process.

I am using Ant Script for performing the builds.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this task??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [Dynamic Parameter Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in) to add something like that.

The plugin allows creating a build parameters, which default value(s) are generated by a Groovy script. The Groovy script is executed each time the build is triggered and allows generating default value(s) according to the current build context (e.g. current user-name, current date/time, etc. or more complex Groovy scripts). The Groovy script can be executed either on the master or on the slave where the build is executed. This can be configured from the build configuration page.

So you could script getting the latest tag for example.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011358/how-can-i-checkout-different-subversion-tags-branches-of-the-same-java-project-w